# Does libc6-i386 compile 64-bit executables?

Tags: 64-bit, c, glibc

I have libc6-i386 installed on my 64-bit capable Intel i3 processor.

Should I rather install the amd64-versions of libc or stick to the i386 as I have an Intel processor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** If you are running the 64-bit version of Ubuntu and you're invoking GCC as `gcc` (for C) or `g++` (for C++), *you need not be worried about the presence of `libc-i386` on your system.* A 64-bit system with a working compiler will produce binaries that link against the proper, 64-bit version of libc.

> Does libc6-i386 compile 64-bit executables?

`libc-i386` doesn't compile anything because it is not a compiler. The C compiler is [`gcc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gcc.1.html). Both libc binaries and libc header files are important but *passive* in the build process. Code is preprocessed, including information from the header files. It is compiled. It is linked to libc. *libc is not doing any of this*, your build tools--principally `gcc` (in the sense that that's the command you most frequently run to make these things happen)--do this.

If you are running the 64-bit version of Ubuntu and you have a C compiler installed, then you already have the necessary libraries and header files to compile and link programs against a 64-bit implementation of libc. *My guess is that this is the situation you are in.* Note that **the presence of a 32-bit libc does not prevent the 64-bit libc from being used by default** unless you are cross-compiling a 32-bit binary (which you would generally know you were doing, as it requires a bit of effort, and you would probably not be invoking `gcc` as `gcc`). Therefore, you need not be worried about the presence of `libc-i386` on your system.

If you are running the 32-bit version of Ubuntu and you want to *cross-compile* 64-bit binaries, then you'll need something that provides the 64-bit version of libc as well as header files for it. (Header files provided officially in Ubuntu are provided by packages whose names end in `-dev`.) However, while 32-bit binaries can run on a 64-bit operating system, 64-bit binaries cannot run on a 32-bit operating system. So unless you really need to cross-compile, it's usually best to build 64-bit programs in a 64-bit operating system.

*Given the small amount of information you've provided, it would be difficult to give an answer more specific to your situation.*

Comment: Thanks. I had not in mind that libc6 itself is not linking or compiling anything.
You were right, I am running on Ubuntu 64 bit and I'm also compiling for 64 bit.
The problem I initially had was that my gcc couldn't find a function `pthread_atfork` although I used the flag -pthread. But that's another question. :)